# Resizing with sizePane yields wrong animation in jquery-ui-layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-layout

I have two nested layouts the `mainLayout` and the `westlayout` which looks like this:

```
 ____________________________
|        |                  |          
|        |                  |          
|  W-C   |                  |
|        |        C         |
|________|                  |
|        |                  |
|  W-S   |                  |
|________|__________________|
```

The Main layout consists of two panes (West and Center). The westlayout also consists of two panes (Center and South).

Now i added a custom toggler to the west pane of the mainLayout which does `mainLayout.sizePane("west", x)` where x can be 40 or 300 depending on the state of the pane.

The initial state is all panels open up like this:

[image]

When i click the toggler the first time, the complete west Pane will animate to 40px width which works correct. The state looks now like this:

[image]

Now if i click the toggler again the pain is supposed to go back to its initial (300px) width. Again i'm only using `sizePane("west", 300)` on the main Layout. This will basicly work, but during the animation from the 40px state to the 300px state for some reason only the west-south pane is animated and the west-center pane "pops" back to 300px after the west-south pane has finished animating.

During the animation it looks like this:

[image]

The layoutOptions for the panes are prettymuch the default. Here are the differences from the default (every pane has the same):

```
{
            paneSelector                : '.' + $container.attr('class'),
            minSize                     : (subRegion.minSize>0) ? subRegion.minSize : 0,
            size                        : (subRegion.size>=0) ? subRegion.size : "auto",
            initHidden                  : subRegion.hidden,

            fxSpeed                     : 200,
            animatePaneSizing           : true,
            spacing_open                : 3,
            spacing_closed              : 3,
            triggerEventsDuringLiveResize : true,
            resizerDblClickToggle: false,
            onresize                    : onResize,
}
```

- Is there something i have to note when using `sizePane` with nested layouts ?
- Am i missing any call to child layouts or something?

Comment: Can you recreate this on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: No, the question is from 2013 and i think we had a workaround these days but its not that relevant anymore.